# Need assistance with CSS in website

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website using my own design, and I had a complication recently.  It's about the way the menu style is positioned. I find this problem hard to explain, so firstly, I'll show the images. 
It should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFi8O.jpg 
It looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miOnb.jpg

As you can see, It's a simple horizontal menu with seperators between menu items, but the tricky part is the corner. In the image where everything works perfectly, I use a messy code, that's not compatable with lists, which I will need for drop-down menus later.

So, this is the messy code:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu-item">

<img src="images/top_menu_edge.png" style="margin-left:-23px;"/> <span style="margin-right:10px"> 1aaaa <span class="ms"></span> 2bbbb <span class="ms"></span> 3 </span>

</div>
```

The span.ms is just the menu seperator. As for all the other parts, I'm gonna show a css code.

```
#menu-item
{
position: absolute; /* The absolute position shouldn't be a problem, because everything is contained in div#header, and it's position is relative. */
bottom: 12px;
right: 0;
height: 34px;
background-position: bottom right;
z-index: 5;
color: #192c51;

}
.menu
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
height: 34px;
background-image: url('images/top_menu_bg.png');
background-position: bottom right;
z-index: 5;
color: #192c51;
```

}

And this is the code that's fixed up, but for some reason, the image is not working:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu-item">

<div class="menu-item">

<img src="images/top_menu_edge.png" style="margin-left:-23px;"/>

<ul id="nav">

<li>  Pagrindinis </li>
<li> Apie mus </li>
<li> Paslaugos </li>
<li> Kontaktai </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And the extra css lines for ul and li:

```
#nav
{
list-style:none;
float:left;
}
#nav > li {
float: left;
}
#nav li+li
{
background:url('images/top_menu_sep.png') no-repeat top left;
padding-left:10px;
}
```

That's pretty much it, and I don't really get it why the  tag ruins it all, yet I need it to do it. Does anyone have any subjections, how to fix it, or could show me the way? I'd be really thankful.

Cheers :)

Comment: `Need assistance with CSS in website` That ain't a question...

Comment: @Martijn Thank you, that solved it for me, can't believe it's that easy, and also thanks for the explanation. I owe you!

Comment: Made is as a reply so it can be marked as answer for future users who dont reead comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give elements float, they will not have width if you place a non-float element nexto it. Remove all the floats and switch to display: inline-block or give everything float